# How to get OEM Logo from UEFI programmability?

Tags: uefi

In Windows 8, when OEM Logo is enabled, you see it during boot and in some other cases (eg. in recovery, when "auto repair" are running). My question is how can I get OEM Logo programmability for use it in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logo is stored in a special ACPI table named BGRT (boot graphics resource table). It's format is described [here](http://www.acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPIspec50.pdf), section 5.2.22.

Comment: the link is dead. please share an another one.

Comment: It was a link to ACPI 5.0 specification, https://uefi.org/specifications has the latest versions of all related specs, ACPI included.